# Is it possible to use class and id combination in this case?

Tags: jquery

I have got a div as shown below

```
<div class="lastItm_Wrap lastItm_Wrapcommon" id="lastwrap789" data-stuff="[1,2,3]" data-vegornonveg="vegterian" data-lastwrapquan="0">        
</div>
```

I am able to fetch the data under stuff as shown below

```
var vendoritemsdata = $("#lastwrap789").data('stuff');
alert(vendoritemsdata);
```

But my question is , is it possible to use class and id combination as

```
var vendoritemsdata = $("#lastwrap789 .lastItm_Wrap").data('stuff');
alert(vendoritemsdata);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5652/

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Just remove the space between the id and the class, like this:

```
$("#lastwrap789.lastItm_Wrap").data('stuff');
```